# Проблемы с keyframes , не работает в -moz-

Tags: css, анимация

Не работает `animation` в Firefox , а в других работает

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.fon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: dinamic 1s infinite steps(4);
 -webkit-animation: dinamic 1s infinite steps(4);
 -moz-animation: dinamic 1s infinite steps(4);
}
@-webkit-keyframes dinamic {
  0% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/1.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  25% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/2.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/3.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  75% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/4.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes dinamic {
  0% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/1.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  25% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/2.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/3.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  75% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/4.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
@keyframes dinamic {
  0% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/1.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  25% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/2.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/3.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  75% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/4.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes dinamic {
  0% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/1.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  25% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/2.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/3.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  75% {
    background: url(http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/4.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mo">
  <img src="http://maxim1978.0fees.us/images/bg.png" alt="">
  <div class="fon"></div>
</div>
```

Этот пример в [песочнице](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ObRWoE?editors=1100)

Comment: А существующую картинку можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле можно ? я не понял

Comment: Не знаю, что не работает в FF, но я в хроме вижу такое: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm6cW.png.

Comment: @Qwertiy а в песочнице тоже не работает ??

Comment: `Error 1016 Ray ID: ... • 2016-11-22 22:15:12 UTC
Origin DNS error` по ссылке на песочницу.

Comment: @Qwertiy   http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ObRWoE?editors=1100  а так тоже не открывается ??!!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30P0D.png - не открывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy  https://jsfiddle.net/bk8koy7j/  - ну фиг знает , вот другая песочница

Comment: Прям как в сниппете: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crv5u.png

Comment: @Qwertiy    http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1870489/94f188c130720d70005e61aa610b69d5    у меня работает

Comment: Странно... Но у меня не работает...

Comment: Я на Винде когда был, такое было у меня - файл hosts  приходилось чистить

Answer (score 1):

В фаерфоксе/IE анимация свойства `background-image` не работает. Я рекомендую вам склеить эти изображения в одно и анимировать свойство `background-position`, а не `background-image`. Также придется избавиться от `background-size: cover`.

Примерно код будет выглядеть вот так, CSS:

```
@keyframes bg-animation {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
```

HTML:

```
.fon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(full-image.png);
  animation: dinamic 1s infinite steps(4);
}
```

Comment: так не будет эффекта спрея - я буду искать другой выход , посмотрите в google chrome как должно выглядеть - блин .. буду искать что то другое

Comment: Если анимировать при помощи steps(), то будет эффект ступенчатой анимации. По крайней мере в хроме я вижу именно такую анимацию.

Comment: У меня есть пример такой анимации на сайте http://www.naukomania.ru/, можно поиграться при помощи девтулс, если изменять время анимации, то будет увеличиваться ступенчатость.